# Cerrar pantalla modal

Tags: modalform

Tengo una ventana modal que abro para agregar datos a la tabla, funciona todo correctamente pero no consigo que se cierre una vez insertado los datos. Pongo el código por si alguien puede ayudarme. Por lo que he visto debería cerrarse con el $('#frmEmployee').modal('hide'); pero no hace nada. No sé dónde estoy fallando y me estoy volviendo un poco loco.

ventana modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
<form id="frmEmployee" class="form">
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-gestionar-empleado" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Datos Tema</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" >x</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="formgroup">
                    <label form="txtdescripcion">Descripción</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descripcion" id="txtdescripcion" placeholder="Descripcion Tema">
                </div>
            </div>               
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" id="btnGuardar" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Codigo de para insertar y dónde quiero cerrar la ventana:

```
   $("#btnGuardar").on('click',function(){
   var data = {
    "descripcion": $("#txtdescripcion").val(),
    "accion": "agregar"
    };
    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: 'post',
        url: 'ajax/temas.ajax.php',

        beforeSend: function () {
            //console.log("Esperando...");
        },
        success: function (respuesta)            {
           toast.fire({
                    icon:'success',
                    title: 'Tema agregado correctamente'
           }),
            table.ajax.reload(null, false);              
        }
        });
        $('#txtdescripcion').val("");
        $('#frmEmployee').modal('hide');   
    });
```

Comment: Si lo consideras necesario, puedes crear un [repro] que pueda ejecutarse en la pregunta misma a través de una snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`). De hacerlo, no olvides "emular" nada más la petición ajax (ya que ese .php no podrá invocarse aquí). Además, reemplaza la etiqueta de la pregunta por etiquetas _relevantes_ (como _bootstrap_, por dar un ejemplo).

Answer (score 0):

Tu código está mal ubicado, deberías acomodarlo de esta manera:

```
  $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: 'post',
        url: 'ajax/temas.ajax.php',

        beforeSend: function () {
            //console.log("Esperando...");
        },
        success: function (respuesta)            {

           toast.fire({
                    icon:'success',
                    title: 'Tema agregado correctamente'
           }),
           //table.ajax.reload(null, false);              
          $('#txtdescripcion').val(""); //Código movido
          $('#modal-gestionar-empleado').modal('hide');   //Código movido
        }
        });

    });
```

Comente una linea de código para que lo pruebes así y veas que funciona ya luego la habilitas, espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero no funciona, ya lo había probado. El refresco de la tabla y el dejar el valor del campo a vacío si que funciona pero el ocultar la ventana modal no.

Comment: Perdona, ese día que te respondí no estaba en mis cávales jaja, te he actualizado la respuesta a la correcta, no revise bien tu código, resulta ser que no estabas indicando el ID correcto de la modal y por eso no se cerraba, ahora mi respuesta debe funcionar perfectamente.